# How can i create multiple divs in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a loop that creates multiple divs that only changes these two variables which I would replace with the IDs from the array.

```js
var ids = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
<div class="post" id={{ids[]}}">
    <blockquote
        class="instagram-media"
        data-instgrm-permalink="https://www.instagram.com/p/{{ids[]}}
        data-instgrm-version="13">
    </blockquote>                
</div>
```

Comment: People are downvoting you because they expected you to provide some JS code with your efforts, even with errors.

Comment: map, join, set innerHTML

Answer (score 3):

Loop through the array, create a string, insert the `id` into the right positions using string literals and append this string to `document.body.innerHTML`:

```js
var ids = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];
ids.forEach(function(e) {
  document.body.innerHTML += `
<div class="post" id=${e}">
           <blockquote
               class="instagram-media"
               data-instgrm-permalink="https://www.instagram.com/p/${e}
               data-instgrm-version="13">
          </blockquote>                
    </div>
`
})
```

```css
.post {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through your array with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and generate a single string of html content.

I've used a helper function `makePost`, but you could just do it in the body of the forEach callback.

Then update the DOM **only once** with the generated content using [Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to avoid layout thrashing.

```js
const ids = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];

const makePost = (id) => `
  <div class="post" id="${id}">
    <blockquote
      class="instagram-media"
      data-instgrm-permalink="https://www.instagram.com/p/${id}"
      data-instgrm-version="13">
      Content - ${id}
    </blockquote>                
  </div>`;

let htmlContent = ''

ids.forEach(id => {
  htmlContent += makePost(id)
})

const d1 = document.getElementById('dynamic-content');
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlContent);
```

```html
<div id="dynamic-content"></div>
```